# Unable to retrieve a row with highest value of a column using row number and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query which  returns one row which has highest price in it for each product.

For Example I have

Table T1

```
Product Price Tax   Location
Pen     10    2.25  A
Pen      5    1.25  B
Pen     15    1.5   A 
Board   25    5.26  A
Board    2    NULL  B
Water    5    10    A
```

The result should be like

```
Product Price Tax   Location       
 Pen     15    1.5   A 
 Board   25    5.26  A
 Water    5    10    A
```

I am using `row number()`  and `group by` to achieve this using the following

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[InferredBestBids]
AS
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY ( SELECT   NULL
                                         ) ) AS id ,
            product ,
            MAX(price) AS Price ,
            MIN(tax) AS Tax ,
            location
    FROM    [dbo].InferredBids_A
    WHERE   NOT ( proce IS NULL
                  AND tax IS NULL
                )
    GROUP BY market ,
            term
GO
```

When I ran the above query, it threw me the error

```
Column 'dbo.InferredBids_A.Location' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

When I tried to group the query results by `location`, it gave me incorrect results by returning multiple rows for a `product` depending on the `location`

Comment: The specified resultset doesn;t require a `MAX()` or `GROUP BY`. It looks like what you'd want is: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by Product ORDER BY Price DESC) AS rn` and a predicate `rn=1` in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

No `GROUP BY` is needed if you get your row_number clauses properly engaged and then just select based on the rownumber. Feel free to add an extra `row_number` call to the front of the outer query if you require it for some other reason. [See the example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/155b20/2).

```
SELECT Product, Price, Tax, Location
FROM (
  SELECT Product, Price, Tax, Location, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Price DESC) as RowID
  FROM InferredBids_A
  ) T
WHERE RowID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you select something that's aggregated you must `GROUP BY` anything else in the select list that is not also aggregated:

```
SELECT Product, Price ,Tax, Location
FROM (SELECT Product, Price ,Tax, Location, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Price DESC) N
    FROM InferredBids_A
    WHERE Price IS NOT NULL AND Tax IS NOT NULL
) T WHERE N = 1
```

(`RANK` will give rows for ties, use `ROW_NUMBER` if you don't care about these)

Answer (score 1):

Making some test data:

```
DECLARE @BestBids TABLE
(
    Product VARCHAR(20),
    Price INT, 
    Tax DECIMAL(10,2),
    Location VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @BestBids
VALUES
('Pen', 10, 2.25, 'A'),
('Pen', 5, 1.25,  'B'),
('Pen', 15, 1.5,   'A'), 
('Board', 25, 5.26,  'A'),
('Board', 2, NULL,  'B'),
('Water', 5, 10,   'A');
```

We get our row number to be set to the highest price for each product.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Price DESC) RN
    FROM @BestBids
) a
WHERE RN=1
```

We wrap the sql and just pick the first row number. Here is the output:

```
Product Price   Tax     Location    RN
Board   25      5.26    A           1
Pen     15      1.50    A           1
Water   5       10.00   A           1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   product ,
                        MAX(price) AS price
               FROM     dbo.InferredBids_A
             )
    SELECT  product ,
            price ,
            tax ,
            location
    FROM    dbo.InferredBids_A tbl
            INNER JOIN cte ON cte.product = tbl.product
                              AND cte.price = tbl.price
```